# Executing / Running a python script from ubuntu server

Tags: python, linux, bash

Can anybody help me how to run a python script through command line?

My python script http://buffis.com/2007/07/25/getting-info_hash-for-xbt-tracker/comment-page-1/

I am using this command `/var/www/hash_info.py /var/www/Muha_Album.7912.torrent`

I have copied dependency file `bencode.py` mentioned in article link above. When I execute the above command I get error **No such file or directory** but when i chmod the file to 644 it says Permission denied the file is present at the location.

I have installed pythong using this command `apt-get install python-gtk2 python-glade2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
python /var/www/hash_info.py /var/www/Muha_Album.7912.torrent
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it says:

```
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Then, the first line, so called [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is the issue here. I guess you need to change it to where your python is really installed. On my Ubuntu installation it's `/usr/bin/python`.

Also, the solution from voyager should work for you as well.

Comment: To run a script from the current directory, after adding the shebang line, make sure you prefix the script name with a dot-slash to indicate that you want to run the file in the current directory, instead of some executable in the system: `./hash_info.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod 744`